# Using DateTime::createFromFormat() without rolling the (wrong) date

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

Let the wrong date `58/57/5654` (or `58.57.5654`) written in a language part of a set of languages in which dates aren't written the same way (*e.g.:* French dates, English dates and German dates). I want to call `DateTime::createFromFormat()` by passing the language's date format and this wrong date, the aim being to retrieve the wrong (or correct) day, month and year according to the language.

**Example.**

1. The French user wrote `58/57/5654` (or `58.57.5654`). So I want to get: `(day, month, year) = (58, 57, 5654)`
2. The English user wrote this same date. I will get: `(day, month, year) = (57, 58, 5654)`.
3. And for the German, it would be the same as French.

## The problem

Using, `DateTime::createFromFormat($the_format, $the_date);` will execute a roll on the day, month and year values of the date if the given ones are wrong. For exemple: `string(10) "58/57/5654"` becomes the correct, **but unwanted**, date `string(10) "28/10/5658"`.

How could I avoid this roll?

See: https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: either use a localized date-library like moment.js or force the user to use a specific format. I'd aim to solve this on the client side already. Also first verification to avoid confusion (like the incorrect date 58/57) should happen there.

Comment: Is there any reason behind these invalid dates? I mean, if you have your own date systems, for whatever reason, you cannot stick to standard classes since they don't know your odd system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to disable this feature, but you can *check* if this happened:

```
$date = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($format, $dateString);

if(!$date || ($date->format($format) !== $dateString)) {
    throw new InvalidDateException($dateString);
}
```

What we're doing here is checking the provided date string against the date that was created from that date string, this will indicate to us whether the 'rollover', as you put it, has happened.

This will need some adaption to work for your codebase but hopefully, that gives you some general approach to start working with?